# Vue 2 Programmatically Create Toggle Transmissions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have just been taking a look at some example code on the Vue JS documentation about transitions. I am trying to add buttons to each list item and give them the ability to toggle content within each list.

Here is an example of my instance:

```
<ul id="demo">
 <li>
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
 </li>

 <li>
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
 </li>
</ul>

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

How can I programatically allow my two `<li>` tags to have their own buttons that only shows the content within itself?

I know I could just add another data object called `show2` and amend the button to `<button v-on:click="show2 = !show2">` however this is a manual process that I don't want to have to do ever time a new `<li>` is added.

How can I programatically achieve this within Vue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create another component, let's call `Togglable`. You can pass the content with props or using slots as shown on the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots)

With the new component you can use it for each li. Check `v-for` as well if your data is dynamic too.

It is going to look similar to this:

`<togglable content="hello" button-name="Toggle"></togglable>`